# What is the painting in the end credits of 'La Piovra' season 4?

Tags: reference, la-piovra

The painting in the end credits scene of *La Piovra* (Season 4) depicts two screaming girls and a burning car, obviously some modern art, but who's the painter and is there any story to it?

May be seen, e.g., here:

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8aEY4T22UY]